# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'poetry.console'

Tags: python, python-poetry

Had install `poetry` lib, when I add to `pyproject.toml` next setting:

```
[tool.poetry-dynamic-versioning]
enable = true
vcs = "git"
style = "pep440"
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/a-kostenko/.poetry/bin/poetry", line 17, in <module>
    from poetry.console import main
  File "/home/a-kostenko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry_dynamic_versioning/__init__.py", line 409, in alt_import
    module = _state.original_import_func(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'poetry.console'
```

help please, what is wrong?

Answer (score 17):

Try to do which\where poetry. Maybe you have multiple poetry installations.
Note that there are two versions now `get-poetry.py` and `install-poetry.py`
So make sure that you uninstall both and then do a fresh install.

First uninstall everything.

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org > install-poetry.py
python install-poetry.py --uninstall
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py > get-poetry.py
python get-poetry.py --uninstall
```

Then install again with new `install-poetry.py` script

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org > install-poetry.py
python install-poetry.py
```

Then make sure if the path is in environment:

```
$HOME/.local/bin for Unix
%APPDATA%\Python\Scripts on Windows
```

Finally test

```
poetry --version
```

Comment: Update to this - as of now, https://install.python-poetry.org is the canonical source for the install-poetry.py script. These steps still work, but it's better to replace each instance of `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/install-poetry.py > install-poetry.py` with `curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org > install-poetry.py`

Answer (score 8):

Here is the PowerShell way.

## Uninstall

```
$ul = ("https://install.python-poetry.org",
       "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/install-poetry.py",
       "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py")

$ul |% { (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ -UseBasicParsing).Content | py - --uninstall }
```

## Reinstall

```
$ul |% { (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ -UseBasicParsing).Content | py -}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it might not recognize the poetry library even though its present in the venv, a simple solution that worked for me was

`pip install poetry`

It will update any existing faulty installation of poetry with the latest stable version.